# How to limit network bandwidth after some data transferred?

Tags: networking, limit, bandwidth, tc, traffic

So the question is in the name of topic. How to limit bandwidth I know.
Using `tc`.
But how to do so after, for example, traffic had reached 500MB.
And after some time reset the limits.

Comment: Maybe pyshaper can do this... See the answer to [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109973/how-to-change-speed-limit-of-running-trickle-instance)

Comment: @StefanSchmiedl no, that's not what I'm looking for :(

Comment: @JagaJaga Could you figure out how to do this? Tomato's QoS does, but I also would like to know how to do this.

Comment: @brauliobo no, I haven't figured out how to do it. Only maybe using `tc` and it's classes. Seems to be very hard or very rare problem.

Comment: @JagaJaga maybe we should look at http://tomato.groov.pl source code

Comment: @brauliobo good idea